# Calling functions with multiple arguments in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have defined a php function:

```
function my_function($text = '', $relative = false, $icon = true) {
//do something
}
```

It works as expected with default values. But when I want to change the value of one variable it doesn't work:

```
my_function($icon = false); // this doesn't change anything
```

I have to call it with all variables to make changes take effect:

```
my_function($text = '', $relative = false, $icon = false); // this changes the output
```

I am working in php 5.4.1 and Wordpress. What I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: don't use the formal parameter names inside the parameter parts when "using" that function. so e.g. its "my_function(false)" in the first example.

Comment: That was proposed as a php feature a long time ago. It never made it in though. I liked the idea, although I cant say I'd use it all that often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must** provide values for any default arguments to the left (in function signature) of the argument you want to change.

So given the function:

```
function my_function($text = '', $relative = false, $icon = true) {
//do something
}
```

Here are some examples:

```
// $text = "foo", $relative = false, $icon = true
my_function("foo"); 

// $text = "", $relative = true, $icon = true
my_function("", true) 

// $text = "", $relative = false, $icon = false
my_function("", false, false)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_function($icon = false);
```

You can't do that in PHP.  Well, you can, but it doesn't do what you think it does.  What this does is:

1. Sets `$icon` to `false`
2. Passes `false` as the 1st parameter to `my_function`

If you want to change the third parameter, you need to also pass the first two.

```
my_function('', false, true);
```

Note: I think it's python that lets you call functions like that, to set only the Xth parameter.

Comment: I frequently use this syntax in PHP, but yes, it doesn't let one skip the previous parameters. I tend to use the old-style 'private' naming convention to indicate it shouldn't be reused: `my_function($_icon = false);`.

Comment: What do you mean by "old-style 'local' naming convention"? How does that indicate "it shouldn't be reused"?

Comment: It won't _stop_ its reuse, of course. But its prefix is enough for me to know I won't use it elsewhere as a proper variable in the current scope.

Comment: Old style 'local' - my mistake, I meant 'private' (fixed). Prior to PHP getting a specific mechanism for class attribute visibility, the convention was (iirc) to use an underscore prefix for private variables.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong, that's how PHP works.
And when you're calling a function, you shouldn't put variables in the parameter list as you might get undesired results as the variables will be assigned those values. So, this is fine:

```
my_function('', false, false);
```

or:

```
my_function($text, $relative, $icon);
```

or anything in between, no need to assign values.

Answer (score 1):

You may use below code:

```
<?php

function my_function($arg = array("text"=>'Default',"relative"=>false,"icon"=>false))
{
  extract($arg);
      $text = isset($text)?$text:"";
      $relative = isset($relative)? $relative : false;
      $icon = isset($icon)? $icon : false;

      //do something

}

my_function(array("icon"=>true));

?>
```

**WARNING:** if you use this way. you should initialise the variable or check the if it is exists.